# rxJava 2.0 How to combine result from two sql table into one JsonObject

Tags: java, json, postgresql, rx-java2, vert.x

I am having problem with fixing results from two tables into one JsonObject. So far I did this, but this implementation gives me first all objects from one table, and then the objects from another table.

```
 Single<JsonObject> getAllPersons() {
   return jdbc.rxQuery("SELECT * FROM persons")
    .zipWith(jdbc.rxQuery("SELECT * FROM passports"),
                   (person,passport)->new JsonObject().put("persons",person).put("passports",pasport));
```

The way I want to do this is to add all columns for one `person` and then to add two more columns from second table that is `passport` referenced by foreign key, and to do that for every person in table. The result should look something like this

> {
>   "id":1,
>   "name":"John",
>   "lname":"Doe",
>   "birthDate":"1.1.2000",
>   "**passport**":{
>   "passportId:"1234",
>   "country:"America",
>   "expireDate:"1.1.2020
>   }
>   }

I need somehow to emits every row from `persons` separated and then to execute something like this `SELECT * FROM passport WHERE passportId = person.getInteger("passportId")`

Comment: Why not just use a single query with a join statement? e.g. something like:
"SELECT persons.id, persons.name, persons.lname, persons.birthDate, passport.passportId, passport.country, passport.expireDate FROM persons INNER JOIN passport ON persons.passportId=passport.passportId"

Comment: The `Single` you get from rxQuery will eventually give you all the results in the same object. That's why `zipWith` gives you all results in one single event. I would recommend to follow @chris advice and let the database join results for you. It's built for this kind of job.